# Bit Bucket Login error "Operation is forbidden" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, authentication, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I can easily log into my account in browser but when I try to login inside visual studio it shows the error.

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved!

Any user with an Atlassian account created on or after UTC 00:00 on 13 September 2021 must use a Bitbucket Cloud generated App Password for all git operations over HTTPS and for REST API authentication. In this case, please try to access Visual Studio using an App password.

Make sure you type in your username (not your mail id) and the App password to get access to the BitBucket extension while using Visual Studio.